# Is there a way to use a cache system with my nodejs application to minimize the number of requests

Tags: node.js, caching

My application currently looks like this:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaaEp.png)
The problem is that the number of requests made is consequent for a simple request returning an article for example. I was wondering if it was possible to minimize the number of requests by using a caching system in my application? :
[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCIa9.png)
Or is there a simpler way?

I've seen that redis could be a solution, but it's a pretty heavy system and it's going to be complicated to synchronize everything properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is good for you, in the meanwhile, the cache solution depends on your expectation.

- If you would like to deploy one replica of your application, in-memory cache is good for you since it's much more easier to manage. E.g. nodecache.
- If you need to deploy many replicas as the requests increased some day, that is to say you need load balancing function, there is a problem to sync up the data in in-memory cache among different replicas. At this points, redis is right for you.

btw, Redis is not heavy at all...

Comment: Agree with all of this, Redis is super lightweight and easy to use and its mostly single threaded atomic architecture means synchronization is generally not an issue.